# win32 GUI display numbers from int variable in window

Tags: c++

```
int vari=10;
MessageBox(NULL, "<3 FAMOUS 10 <3 ","Lesson1", MB_OKCANCEL);
```

I want to display vari in below message box, so how I can?

Comment: Learn how to incorporate that number into a string, then you got it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CString::Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6.aspx) to create a message similar to `printf`:

```
#include <afx.h>

int vari=10;
CString msg;
msg.Format( _T("value = %d"), vari );
MessageBox(NULL, msg, _T("Lesson1"), MB_OKCANCEL);
```

Comment: You forget to place `"Lesson1"` string to `_T(..)` or `TEXT(...)` macro )

Answer (score 1):

You can format your output string by printing values to it, than display it as dialog message:

```
char buffer[0xff];
int value = 10;
sprintf(buffer, "the value of variable is: %d\n", value);

MessageBoxA(NULL, buffer, "Lesson1", MB_OK);
```